# I can see the changes I made (as an administrator) but as an anonymous user, I can't

Tags: views, 8, nodes, hooks

***Have you had any problems like this before? I appreciate your help.***

When I'm an admin and update a node (custom module), I can see the changes I made (as `an administrator`). However, when I'm an `anonymous user`, just to check the data, I can't see the changes I made. (note: I have flushed the site, it will work, but only when I run flush)

I thought it was something related with the permission, from a Custom module I created, but I'm not sure of that. I included a `permission.yml` file and gave full access. It didn't work.

find the attached images:

[image]
[image]
I had built the code in the Controller folder/file:
I have two public functions called retrieveArrayOne and retrieveArrayTwo. Each one has different data for me to query later (retrieving the data from these two functions).

```
public function mainviewlist() {
  $array1 = array($this->retrieveArrayTwo());
  $array2 = array($this->retrieveArrayOne());
  $retrieveData = array_merge($array1, $array2);
  $content = "<H2></H2>";
  foreach ($retrieveData as $key1 => $finalValues) {
    if ($key1 == 0) {
      foreach ($finalValues as $disCrop) {
        $content .= "<details>";
        $content .= '<summary>' . $disCrop . '</summary>';
        $content .= "</details>";
      }
    }
  }
  return array(
    '#type'     => 'markup',
    '#markup'   => $content,
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array(
        'modulename/modulename',

      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the function from the $array1 and array2. Both are similar.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'content-type-name');
$query->sort('title', 'ASC');
$entity = $query->execute();
$options = array();

foreach ($entity as $n) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($n);
  $options[$node->id()] = $node->getTitle();
  $elementA[] = [//
    'nid'        => $node->get('nid')->value,
    'title'      => $node->get('title')->value,
    'body'       => $node->get('body')->value,
    'field_crop' => $node->get('field_crop')->value,
  ];
}

return $elementA;
```

Comment: This is not a permission issue, this is a caching issue. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-api

Comment: If this is a caching issue, then it shouldn't even work as an administrator. After I update a node from a Content Type, I can see the changes I made as an administrator but not as an anonymous user or after I log-out from the site.

Comment: the problem is that I can't see the changes as an anonymous user or have access to see the content I made without logging in.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found the problem.

In my routing file, I was missing:

```
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE
```

That fixed it.